# How can I return a java.lang.Object value to client on CORBA in my case?

Tags: java, corba, idl, orb, jacorb

I am developing a Corba application.
My IDL interface look like this:

```
interface Transaction {
    ???????? addResource(in TransactionResource resource);
};
```

I would like when a client invoke addResource method for the Transaction reference object, that can be able to return a returned value of Proxy.newProxyInstance(....) to client.

Exemple of the addResource implementation:

```
public ?????? addResource(TransactionResource resource) {
        // creation of a proxy. 
            java.lang.Object o = Proxy.newProxyInstance(ManageDemand.class.getClassLoader() , new Class[] {ManageDemand.class}, new MyInvocationHandler());

        return o;
    }
```

I would like to return the "o" to client, how can I do that?

What is the type of the returned value of addResource() method ? is it org.omg.CORBA.Object? or other type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with normal way.

from my understanding, the idea of CORBA is, it kind of define its internal message representation which is platform neutral (hence its cross platform interoperability).  Just think, if it allow you to give an arbitrary Java Object, if the receive side is C++, then how can it suppose to convert it to the C++ representation?

In brief, you can simply use the structures you defined in IDL, and if you really want to return arbitrary object, CORBA is probably not what you want.  Consider things like RMI.

If you really really need to do it, I believe the only way you can do is to do the serialization/deserialization by yourself, and return the "object" as an octet sequence or string.  However, you need to be aware that the object receiver got is still a separate instance of object (and hence the proxies around it).  If the works of those proxies need resources of the server side, then I believe you need to rethink your design.  I don't think there is any solution that can magically link up the remote object with the server side object in such way.

Comment: Thanks Adrian Shum, the program is running well using your idea. The serialization and deserialization is the solution, by sending a sequence of octets which represent my java.lang.Object to client.

Comment: To be honest, although it kind of work in this case, it is the most awkward solution.  I strongly suggest you look into your design and avoid using CORBA in such way.

Comment: I realized that the serialization loses my distributed reference, which exist on the MyInvocationHandler class.
When client deserialise the proxy object, and try to use the distributed reference, it throws exception because it not recognize any Servant :S If you can suggest me some solutions.

Comment: That's why I mentioned " If the works of those proxies need resources of the server side".  What you are looking for is not going to work.  Go ahead and rethink your design that fits with the technology you are using.  CORBA (or even RMI etc) is not going to magically let you transmit an arbitrary object to client side and expect it will magically work.

Answer (score -2):

You should return type of `java.lang.Object` and then at the client side you should be casting it back.

Comment: When i used org.omg.CORBA.Object returned value, i have this error:

Exception in thread "main" org.omg.CORBA.UNKNOWN: Server-side Exception: java.la
ng.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0 cannot be cast to org.omg.CORBA.por
table.ObjectImpl

Comment: Which explain that i can't convert java.lang.Object to org.omg.CORBA.Object

Comment: @Ashish Your answer is ambiguous. Do you mean `java.lang.Object` or `org.omg.CORBA.Object`?

Comment: I am sorry I meant java.lang.Object

Comment: You can't define java.lang.Object on IDL.

Comment: @SaadLamarti In that case, (a) -1 to this answer, and (b) what's your question? The IDL defines the return type, which clearly has to be `org.omg.CORBA.Object;` the code generated by `idlj` specifies the Java interface; and your implementation has to agree with that or it won't compile. I agree with the message: you can't cast a Proxy to `org.omg.CORBA.Object.` What you're trying to do appears to be impossible.

Comment: @Saad can you show me the class which is implementing Transaction interface (which also includes addResource() method). I wanna see what packages you are importing and everything

Comment: @Ashish All you need is the `Transaction` interface itself actually. `idlj` will tell you the rest.

Comment: I resolved the problem, by sending the java.lang.Object through sequence of octets. by using Serialisation and deserialisation. Thanks @EJP & @ Ashish